# Radius of Convergence of Complex Series (Real parts)

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I want to show that if the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is R

Then the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\operatorname{Re}(a_n))z^n$ is greater than or equal to R

I know that $|\operatorname{Re}(a_n)|\le |a_n|$ but I'm not confident in being able to find the radius of convergence so don't know how to use this information to prove this?

Any suggestions of how to start a proof like this would be brilliant

Answer (score 4):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $|\operatorname{Re}(a_n)|\leqslant|a_n|$, and therefore $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|\operatorname{Re}(a_n)|}\leqslant\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. But the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{Re}(a_n)z^n$ are equal to$$\frac1{\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|.}}\quad\text{and to}\quad\frac1{\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|\operatorname{Re}(a_n)|}}$$respectively.